# Animate newly added items in ListView

Tags: android, listview, animation, adapter

How can I animate newly added items in `ListView`?

I have a `adapter` and when I add new items in my list I say `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` the items are added, everything works perfectly, but my problem is I want newly added element to have some animation.

Comment: I've got feeling that this is not an easy task. How many items are you planning to have in your `ListView`?

Comment: Well I want animation to be played every time when new item is added. There is something that changes my data randomly and adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); i called every second, so if there is new data than it is presented on the listview that works perfectlly but problem is that there is no animation . . .

Comment: The reason why I asked about the amount of items, is because you will have more chances to animate your additions to `LinearLayout`. But this is only feasible if you have fairly limited number of views. If you are planning to have say 50+ items in the list, then `LinearLayout` becomes way to expensive.

Comment: well having animated Linearlayout is nice if it is possible, I mean linear layout inside listview as item. Do you know how can I do that ?

Comment: No, I meant `LinearLayout` **instead of** `ListView`.

Answer (score 25):

`Animate` each added element in the `getView()` method of your `Custom Adapter`.

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View v = convertView;

    if (v == null) {
        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getActivity()
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = vi.inflate(R.layout.simple_list_item_1, null);
    }

    ListData o = list.get(position);
    TextView tt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.toptext);

    tt.setText(o.content);

    Log.d("ListTest", "Position : "+position);
    if(flag == false) {
        Animation animation = AnimationUtils
                .loadAnimation(getActivity(), R.anim.slide_top_to_bottom);
        v.startAnimation(animation);
    }
    return v;
}
```

And thereby achieve the `Animation`.

Comment: have you tried this ?, what about bindView should I override that method too ?

Comment: yes i have tried this and it works for me. i dont think u need to override the bindView method.

Comment: well my problem is if I do not override the bindView method the list is very slow and sluggish, so I will have to find the way to override correctly and tho have the animation played exactly ones. Because if I override in both methods the animation sometimes is played twice

Comment: @ASH What is that flag variable in the line "if(flag == false)"?

Comment: @NiteshKhatri it is used to avoid animating cells that are currently being displayed at that moment

Answer (score 7):

The official docs about animation in Android say that you can set an animation to trigger whenever the layout is changed, using **android:animateLayoutChanges="true"**.

Taken from: http://developer.android.com/training/animation/layout.html

Comment: This example is not a normal list view, it's a scroll view.

Answer (score 5):

Adding this kind of animations is harder than I first thought of. There are two ways depending of the kind of animation you are trying to achieve.

- Using [LayoutAnimationController](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/LayoutAnimationController.html).
  There is an example in the [API demos](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/LayoutAnimation2.html).
- Animating each `View`:

This is quite a hack but the only way I found to add an animation to `ListView`'s children is the following:

You can try notifying the adapter the id of the item you are willing to delete and call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`. This will generate calls to the adapter's `getView()` method. Inside it you can do something like:

```
if ( item.getId() == itemToRemove ) {
 //apply the animation
}
```

After the animation finished you can recall `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` to put everything in place.