# Android - ListView Animations adding / removing

Tags: android, listview, animation

I want animations, if I add or remove some elements in my custom `Item` list.

I tried it using

- [Handler](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8938057/2715720)
- [ListViewAnimaions](https://github.com/nhaarman/ListViewAnimations)

*(and maybe some others I didn't found yet)*

As I said, I have a Custom View with `Item`s and I add always minimum 2 - depends on the situation. The views are all the same custom views - only different texts and HTML style, but that shouldn't matter.
Then I call `notifyDataSetChanged()`.

Both methods above didn't help.
ListViewAnimations resorts my list.
The Handler works sometimes...
and sometimes I've empty views (until I scroll)

Is there any way I can handle that?

**ListViewAnimations** would be nice, if there is an example with `Insertable`. I couldn't adapt it for my situation. The [Appearance Animations](http://nhaarman.github.io/ListViewAnimations/#appearance-animations) worked nice.

Comment: You can use `RecycleView`. It has some default animations when `removing` or `adding` an item to the list. Check [ItemAnimator](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.ItemAnimator.html) for more information

Comment: @hrskrs how to use that with custom `Item`s?

Comment: [here](http://blog.lovelyhq.com/creating-lists-with-recyclerview-in-android/) is an example

Comment: yes it works! - any idea how to highlight an item if I click on the element?

Comment: you can use `xml selector` for focused, clicked, or whatever state. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2562051/listview-item-background-via-custom-selector) is an example